# How can I share resources between projects in Ready!API with SoapUI NG PRO tab?

Tags: xml, resources, soapui

Is there a way to share resources between projects? We're currently working on a single project (XML file) at the moment and each push and pull generates a merge conflict, even if one person is working on a Resource part and another works on the Test Case part. We have to resort to checking the XML line by line and choosing which line to implement every time. I am thinking of having different projects for each sub-app and have the resources placed in a common folder. This way, they can be shared between each sub app and 2 persons can work on the same time without having any merge conflicts. I've seen a Resource directory but it seems that this is only for Data Sources.

[Sample Project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSmW7.png)

Comment: update 3/20/2017 7:24PM (UTC+8) I was able to export the .wadl file from another project folder but if I update the resources from the project where the .wadl came from, the resources on the 2nd project are not updated. Is there a way to have both project's resources updated every time the original project's resources are updated and saved?

Comment: When you say resources, do you mean service and its methods of `wadl` or `swagger definition` or `wsdl`? Clarify otherwise.

Comment: Hi, I've added a screenshot of the sample project. Even if I added resources(Copy of accounts) on the 1st composite project and saved the project, Project2's resources does not update even if I reload it. I'd like to know if there's a way to have Project 2 automatically updated as well whenever I do a change on the 1st project's resources.

Comment: Do you need frequent changes in the resources? And require to update multiple projects? Is that that challenge you want to address?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I'm expecting to happen. It's a project in progress and we're expecting it to grow everyday as sub-apps(more projects) arrive.

Comment: It seems there remains to be no solution to this one at the moment, even on Ready!API's forums: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-can-I-share-resources-between-projects/m-p/138309